# How to identify which button is being pressed on PS4 controller using pygame

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 to control a robotic vehicle. I have successfully linked my PS4 controller to the RPi using `ds4drv`. I have the following code working and outputting "Button Pressed"/"Button Released" when a button is pressed/released on the PS4 controller using `pygame`. I am wondering how to identify which button is exactly being pressed.

**ps4_controller.py**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()

try:
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                print("Button Pressed")
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                print("Button Released")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXITING NOW")
    j.quit()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out a hack.

The PS4 buttons are numbered as the following:

`0 = SQUARE`

`1 = X`

`2 = CIRCLE`

`3 = TRIANGLE`

`4 = L1`

`5 = R1`

`6 = L2`

`7 = R2`

`8 = SHARE`

`9 = OPTIONS`

`10 = LEFT ANALOG PRESS`

`11 = RIGHT ANALOG PRESS`

`12 = PS4 ON BUTTON`

`13 = TOUCHPAD PRESS`

To figure out which button is being pressed I used `j.get_button(int)`, passing in the matching button integer.

Example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()

try:
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                print("Button Pressed")
                if j.get_button(6):
                    # Control Left Motor using L2
                elif j.get_button(7):
                    # Control Right Motor using R2
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                print("Button Released")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXITING NOW")
    j.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! This code snippet came in really handy haha

Answer (score 9):

You are really close! With a few tweaks, you code becomes this instead:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()

try:
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
                print(event.dict, event.joy, event.axis, event.value)
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBALLMOTION:
                print(event.dict, event.joy, event.ball, event.rel)
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                print(event.dict, event.joy, event.button, 'pressed')
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                print(event.dict, event.joy, event.button, 'released')
            elif event.type == pygame.JOYHATMOTION:
                print(event.dict, event.joy, event.hat, event.value)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXITING NOW")
    j.quit()
```

Some resources that I found helpful in writing the up included [pygame's event documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html), the use of python's `dir` function to see what properties a python object has, and the [documentation for pygame's parent C library, SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/) if you wanted a deeper explanation of what the property actually means. I included both the dictionary access version (using `event.dict`) as well as the property-access version (using just `event.whatever_the_property_name_is`). Note that `event.button` only gives you a number; it is up to you to manually create a mapping of what each button number means on your controller. Hope this clears it up!

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 Glad you found it helpful! Also thanks for sharing your button mapping findings in your answer, those are very useful!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if there are people looking for a solution on this still, I have created a module: pyPS4Controller that has all the button events on the controller already mapped and they can be overwritten like so:

```py
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller


class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def on_x_press(self):
       print("Hello world")

    def on_x_release(self):
       print("Goodbye world")

controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False)
# you can start listening before controller is paired, as long as you pair it within the timeout window
controller.listen(timeout=60)
```

This is just an example for 1 event. There are more events that can be overwritten such as:

```
on_x_press
on_x_release
on_triangle_press
on_triangle_release
on_circle_press
on_circle_release
on_square_press
on_square_release
on_L1_press
on_L1_release
on_L2_press
on_L2_release
on_R1_press
on_R1_release
on_R2_press
on_R2_release
on_up_arrow_press
on_up_down_arrow_release
on_down_arrow_press
on_left_arrow_press
on_left_right_arrow_release
on_right_arrow_press
on_L3_up
on_L3_down
on_L3_left
on_L3_right
on_L3_at_rest  # L3 joystick is at rest after the joystick was moved and let go off
on_L3_press  # L3 joystick is clicked. This event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_L3_release  # L3 joystick is released after the click. This event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_R3_up
on_R3_down
on_R3_left
on_R3_right
on_R3_at_rest  # R3 joystick is at rest after the joystick was moved and let go off
on_R3_press  # R3 joystick is clicked. This event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_R3_release  # R3 joystick is released after the click. This event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_options_press
on_options_release
on_share_press  # this event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_share_release  # this event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_playstation_button_press  # this event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
on_playstation_button_release  # this event is only detected when connecting without ds4drv
```

Full documentation is available @ https://github.com/ArturSpirin/pyPS4Controller

Answer (score -2):

```
if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
        if j.get_button(0):
            PXV = -0.1
        if j.get_button(2):
            PXV = 0.1
    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
        if j.get_button(0) or j.get_button(2):
            PXV = 0
```

joy button down works but PXV(player x velocity)
does not get reset back to zero when i release my controller