# pygame.error: Invalid joystick device number

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()
```

When I run this code on my Raspberry-Pi I am getting back the following error:

```
  j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
pygame.error: Invalid joystick device number
```

This code was working a couple months ago, but something has clearly changed and I can not figure out what since the documentation is exactly the same as before. Any help or knowledge on the issue would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Here is my code from 5 months ago when the project was working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557583/how-to-identify-which-button-is-being-pressed-on-ps4-controller-using-pygame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have a controller connected to the Pi.

In my case, I wasn't running `ds4drv`.

In another terminal window run:

`sudo ds4drv`

and connect your DS4 controller.

https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv

Comment: Is there a solution for Windows users?