# Can I detect inputs from specific usb ports in python?

Tags: python, input

So I picked up a usb arcade button set, and I want to use both for a game I'm making. I have used evtest, but I'm pretty sure both encoders have the same inputs and I don't want to have incorrect movements. I am using Pygame if that helps.

Comment: you cannot work with a specific USB port, but you can work with a specific device

Comment: Are these articles helpful? [Chapter 10: Controllers and Graphics - Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=controllers_and_graphics), [How to identify which button is being pressed on PS4 controller using pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46557583/9014308), [pygame.joystick - pygame 2.0.0.dev5 documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html), [Full Joystick Example](http://arcade.academy/examples/joystick.html)